# Google Play shows - Your device isn't compatible with this version for Samsung Galaxy tab 2 and Google Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-market-filtering

When I published my app to Google play store and I tried downloading it on my Google Nexus 7 , I get the message "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

My Manifest file is declared like this:-

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ApplicationTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyFormsTabActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>      
</application>
```

Comment: In support screens i have allowed all the devices , so how can this be a problem!!

Comment: Do you have a link to the app on the Play Store?

Comment: Odd... it shows up for the XOOM tablet. My only suggestion is to add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />`, though Nexus 7 is GPS-enabled so this shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

This implies using the camera feature, which is different from the *front-facing camera*, as the N7 has. Make the camera feature explicit and optional. Details: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html

Answer (score 1):

Got it..!!

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html

Well android permissions normally are not used as filters if you have specified  attribute. In above case what happened was that I had declared the CAMERA permission , but Google Nexus 7 didn't had a camera( only has front camera). so Google Play filtered out the device.

So In order to solve this problem the best practice would be,

**
If in our application manifest we have asked the permission to use any hardware feature  then We should also declare the uses-feature attribute for that with android:required="false".
**