# My app is not listed on the android market anymore

Tags: android, google-play, manifest, compatibility

This happens only on few devices for example the Motorola motto X device.

When I use a direct link to find the app I get the following message:

> your device isn't compatible with this version

the install button is not available.

I made extensive search:

- [Google Play shows - Your device isn't compatible with this version
  for Samsung Galaxy tab 2 and Google Nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968183/google-play-shows-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-for-samsung-g)
- [“your device isn't compatible with this version”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670002/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version)
- [android - “your device isn't compatible with this version”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313927/android-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version)
- [Play store reports “Your device isn't compatible with this version”
  but it installs via adb just fine on Nexus7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484209/play-store-reports-your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-but-it-insta)

It seems to be related to the manifest file but I am not sure which permisson is filtering out.

I tried adding `android:required="false"` on all of them but did not work:

```
<!-- Google Maps Android API -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>

<!-- phone permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false" />

<!-- GCM Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- Special Permissions -->
<permission
    android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" android:required="false" />

<!-- camera -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:required="false" />
```

Also added compability for all screens:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

Again, did not help... What else could be the reason, is there anyway to find out why it is not compatible.

I feel like I am shooting in the dark, please advice.

Comment: Sorry, misread the permission. Fixed my comment.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein arent those the larger ones? I could see the app on tablets but not on the motto X which is a small screen phone, should I remove the whole `<compatible-screens>`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein ok let me try this , will get back to you in a few thanks

Comment: @FrankN.Stein you were right, if you post as answer happy to accpet

Comment: Yep. Done. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Manifest, `xxhdpi` screens aren't listed in the supported screens, as well as `xxxhdpi` ones.

Tablets usually are `hdpi` or even `mdpi`, in **density** (number of pixels per square inch). **Resolution** (number of pixels in width and height) is something else.

I'd back-up the Manifest and store it somewhere (just in case). then remove the `<compatible-screens>` section - just to try out.

You should be then compatible with a larger variety of devices.

[Documentation for `<compatible-screens>` also state the following:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

> Caution: Normally, **you should not use this manifest element**. Using
>   this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your
>   application, by not allowing users to install your application if they
>   have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed.
>   You should use it only as a last resort, when the application
>   absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead
>   of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting
>   Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens
>   using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and
>   densities.

Comment: Thank you @meda for adding a valuable content. Just be patient - I can't upvote your question for an hour (I prematureky finished my votes for today). It's a good question, and deserves a positive feedback.